# SSH with keys not working on service, but does work on demand (ossec agentless)

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to set up SSH authentication using keys (for OSSEC agentless monitoring).

- I have generated a key file on the calling server using `su -u ossec ssh-keygen`.
- I copied the public key (/var/ossec/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to the target server (`/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
- When executing `sudo -u ossec ssh root@targetserver` I am prompted to enter the root password.

I then tried booting a second instance on the target server with  `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222` and connecting to it using `sudo -u ossec ssh root@192.168.123.9 -p 2222`. It works perfectly, I get logged in without entering the root password of the target server.

Why isn't it working on the "default" service (port 22)? Has it something to do with selinux?

Comment: On Stackoverflow there was an identical post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741574/redhat-6-oracle-linux-6-is-not-allowing-key-authentication-via-ssh  Could you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it worked by disabling selinux so I was able to broaden my search.
I stumbled upon this [blog post](http://blog.rem.co/blog/2013/02/19/selinux-allowing-ssh-public-key-authentication/) which suggest to run `restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh`. That solved my problem.